# MacOSX programming question here or at stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, support, site-scope, migration

I wonder if I should ask a MacOSX programming question here or at stackoverflow.

What is the rationale for asking here versus there and how does that decision work with the discouragement of cross posting the exact same question on more than one site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Programming questions should be asked on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 7):

Cross posting is discouraged because questions can be migrated, and a cross-post will lead to a duplicate question, which the community, in turn, also discourages.

I have never seen an online community where cross-posting was acceptable.

Comment: Interestingly enough, [this very question is a cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89483/156620).

Comment: @Bavarious that is so meta.... O_O